# Redirect_to with variable fir destination link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, url-rewriting

I have a site where you can enter the name of a business after the domain and if it exists it is displayed. E.g. www.mysite.com/BUSINESS_NAME. I do this through a route:

```
match ':id' => 'businesses#show', :via => [:get]
```

It essentially means that a new custom URL is created for each new business that signs up. At the moment each time a new business is created (create form submitted) I am redirected to something like

```
http://localhost:3000/businesses/42
```

This is expected as I use:

```
redirect_to @business
```

How am I able to redirect to the newly created business and make the URL look like

```
www.mysite.com/BUSINESS_NAME   instead of   http://localhost:3000/businesses/42
```

I thought about making logic in the show action that would work for either URL request but it doesn't look very nice to the end user seeing an ID - I am sure there is something in Rails to mask this sort of information and still pass the ID parameter.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can make the url as user friendly.So user can see the simple url that dosen't use the id.

There is a gem in rails that easily solve your problem.

[Friendly_id](http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=friendly_id)